# use Next 13 searchParams and route params with SSG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm creating a blog using `Next.js` app directory. I have route that looks like this:

`/blogs/category/[name]`

This will show all the blogs withing the category, and is an `SSG` page, using the `generateStaticParams()`. Here is the code:

```
export default async function Blogs({ params: { name } } : {
    params: { name: string }
}) {

    const blogs = await fetchBlogs({ category: decodeURIComponent(name) })

    const blogCount = await fetchBlogCount({ category: name })
    return <>Rest of the component......</>
}


export async function generateStaticParams() {
    const categories = await fetchCategories()

    return categories.map(category => ({
        name: category
    }))
}
```

This works fine as an SSG page, and the pages are built at buildtime. But now I want to be able to search for a blog within a category, so I need to use a `searchParam`. My question is how can I keep this page as an SSG while being able to use SearchParams?

What I want is for this page to run on the server only if there is a `searchParam` otherwise show the pre-rendered page.

I've tried this, but I'm getting `Error: Dynamic server usage: searchParams.search` I know I can fix this by adding:

`export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'`, but I want this page to stay an SSG page.

```
export default async function Blogs({ params: { name }, searchParams: { search } }: {
    params: { name: string },
    searchParams: {
        search?: string
    }
}) {

    const blogs = await fetchBlogs({ category: decodeURIComponent(name), search })

    const blogCount = await fetchBlogCount({ category: name })

    return <>Rest of the component......</>
}
```

Comment: Can you please ellaborate "What I want is for this page to run on the server only if there is a searchParam otherwise show the pre-rendered page." I assume your searchParam is within the array returned by generateStaticProps right ? . So actually the way it works is if the searchParam is found in array generated by generateStaticProps it will SSG the page else it will dynamically fetch, I hope you know this . What you actually want to achieve may I know ?